# How to make sticky header for mobile by custom CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, mobile

I'm building my first web site now, using OceanWP free theme 
I was able to write CSS for sticky header for desktop but unfortunately I can't do the same for Mobile.

the css code I'm using now is:

```
#site-logo {
float: left;
left: -0px;
z-index: 100000;
position:fixed;
text-align: left;   
height:60px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#site-navigation {
background:#B4C5E4;
height:70px;
opacity:0.9;
z-index:170;
margin:0 auto;
border-bottom:0px solid
#dadada;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
text-align: center;

}
```

**The code works great on desktop but doesn't work at all on mobile**

How do I make a sticky header on mobile using only CSS?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share what you've tried until up now.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score -1):

You might use this code:

```
#sticky-header {
background:#52694;
height:50px;
z-index:170;
margin:0 auto;
border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
text-align: center;}
```

Replace #sticky-header with the CSS ID of your nav menu.

Comment: Hi Jani, Thanks for the response! I replaced and unfortunately it doesn't work